# Class method to write JSON to file

Tags: python, json

I'm struggling with the following class method:

```
class Base:
    def to_json_string(list_dictionaries):
        if list_dictionaries is None or len(list_dictionaries) == 0:
            return "[]"
        return json.dumps(list_dictionaries)

    @classmethod
    def save_to_file(cls, list_objs):
        filename = cls.__name__ + ".json"
        with open(filename, "w") as f:
            f.write(cls(Base.to_json_string(list_objs)))
```

I have a class Rectangle that inherits from Base. To which I can pass in the class method *save_to_file* and it will create me a file named Rectangle.json with a list of objects JSON formatted.

Example:

```
r1 = Rectangle(10, 7, 2, 8)
r2 = Rectangle(2, 4)
Rectangle.save_to_file([r1, r2])

with open("Rectangle.json", "r") as file:
    print(file.read())
```

Output:

```
[{"y": 8, "x": 2, "id": 1, "width": 10, "height": 7}, {"y": 0, "x": 0, "id": 2, "width": 2, "height": 4}]
```

But it's raising a TypeError message "TypeError: Object of type Rectangle is not JSON serializable"

I'm new to OOP in Python and still don't figure out how to use *cls* properly. So my error lays here:

```
@classmethod
def save_to_file(cls, list_objs):
    filename = cls.__name__ + ".json"
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        f.write(cls(Base.to_json_string(list_objs)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is with the assumption that the `json` module automatically knows how to transform your custom object into JSON. You just need to fix your `to_json_string`, that's all. This *could* work:

```
def to_json_string(list_dictionaries):
    if not list_dictionaries:
        return "[]"
    return json.dumps([element.__dict__ for element in list_dictionaries])
```

However, using `__dict__` is pretty brittle, it's better to define specifically inside the `Rectangle` class what attributes should be part of the dict/how it should be serialized.

It's also not considered good style to just attach plain functions to classes, if it has nothing to do with `Base` functionality (which it doesn't, if it isn't a class or instance method), I would just keep it outside the class. Or at least use a `@staticmethod` decorator so noone accidentally calls `some_object.to_json_string()` (which wouldn't work).

Comment: It kinda worked, but it retrieves the dictionaries with "_Rectangle__width": 10 instead of just "width" and so on... Thing is, I also have a method to_dictionary() that does it for me. So it ended up with the desired output. Thanks!

Comment: That's your own fault for needless double underscores though (you almost never need to save the data in `self.__width` etc., this isn't Java).